# R Mutate Column That Represents the Mean of Many Other Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to add a column in my DataFrame that represents the mean of many other columns (items that represent a single construct).

The dataframe has many other columns but particularly columns eng1, eng2, eng3...engN where N is a large number and I want to take the mean of all the eng* columns and add that mean as a new column to my dataset.

I was able to do this with the following code:

```
narrow_ds # ... initialization of dataframe
library(dplyr)
narrow_ds <- bind_cols(narrow_ds, (narrow_ds %>% 
select(starts_with("eng")) %>% mutate(eng=rowMeans(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
select(eng))
```

It seems that having the na.rm=TRUE requirement forced me to jump through some hoops.

My question is whether there are more straightforward ways to do this?

Comment: Do you want to take the mean of all the columns, or just a subset?

Comment: It should be a mean of just the (quite a few) columns prefaced with eng. There are other columns in the dataset I don't want to include in the mean. (I'll edit the question to clarify.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stealing sample data from @MKR, in base R:

```
DF$eng <- rowMeans(DF[startsWith(names(DF),"eng")], na.rm = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id  eng1  eng2  eng3      eng
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1    50    NA    20 35.00000
# 2     2    NA   100    10 55.00000
# 3     3    20   150    80 83.33333
# 4     4    30   200    40 90.00000
```

Comment: `startsWith()`, had not come across that function before. God call.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is the one I used in my code.

Answer (score 6):

You are very much in right direction. You can avoid `bind_cols` with a tweak in your code. Moreover, the `NA` are supported even in `rowMeans`. I have modified the sample data used by `@Tung` to include few `NAs` as well. The solutions can be as:

**Option#1:** Using `dplyr` in similar approach as OP.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% mutate(eng = rowMeans(select(.,starts_with("eng")), na.rm = TRUE))

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id  eng1  eng2  eng3   eng
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  50.0    NA  20.0  35.0
# 2     2  NA     100  10.0  55.0
# 3     3  20.0   150  80.0  83.3
# 4     4  30.0   200  40.0  90.0
```

**Option#2:** Using `apply`

```
DF$eng <- apply(DF[,grep("eng",names(DF))], 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

DF
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id  eng1  eng2  eng3   eng
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  50.0    NA  20.0  35.0
# 2     2  NA     100  10.0  55.0
# 3     3  20.0   150  80.0  83.3
# 4     4  30.0   200  40.0  90.0
```

**Sample data:**

```
DF = data_frame(id = 1:4,
                eng1 = c(50, NA, 20, 30), 
                eng2 = c(NA, 100, 150, 200), 
                eng3 = c(20, 10, 80, 40))
```

Comment: Thanks for the two options.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with the same issue, I think the easiest way to make operations (mean, sd, sums, etc) whitn colums is by useing "rowwise()" comand from "dplyr", and grouping target columns with "c()" inside the wanted operation:

```
C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)
C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
C3<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3)


library(dplyr)

DF <- DF %>% 
     rowwise() %>% mutate(Avg = (mean(c(C1, C2, C3), na.rm = T))) 

DF
   ID    C1    C2    C3    Avg
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         3     3     5  3.67
2 B         2     7     4  4.33
3 C         4     3     3  3.33
4 D         4     4     6  4.67
5 E         5     5     3  4.33
```

Also one can ensure that this operation ends on a single data frame doing the following:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(DF %>% 
         rowwise() %>% mutate(Avg = (mean(c(C1, C2, C3), na.rm = T))))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26189666)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Example data
set.seed(1)
dtf <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10000), ncol=1000))
nam <- replicate(ncol(dtf), paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE), collapse=""))
colnames(dtf) <- nam
```

I didn't name the columns 'eng*', but this is functionally the same.
Only the columns whose name starts with an `A` will be averaged.

```
eng <- rowMeans(dtf[, grep("^A", colnames(dtf))], na.rm=TRUE)
dtf <- cbind(eng, dtf)

summary(dtf)[,1:4]
# #      eng         BRTCBDWVWA     COCSSUQNLA     FIOULRNUXL  
# Min.   :4535   Min.   : 618   Min.   :1764   Min.   : 134  
# 1st Qu.:4780   1st Qu.:2922   1st Qu.:3805   1st Qu.:2254  
# Median :5187   Median :6008   Median :5916   Median :3604  
# Mean   :5107   Mean   :5513   Mean   :5580   Mean   :4174  
# 3rd Qu.:5337   3rd Qu.:8386   3rd Qu.:7557   3rd Qu.:5840  
# Max.   :5739   Max.   :9442   Max.   :9903   Max.   :9329
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pmap_dbl`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) to loop through every row of your data frame. Here is an example with some random data

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF = data_frame(eng1 = c(50, 40, 20, 30), 
                eng2 = c(130, 100, 150, 200), 
                eng3 = c(20, 10, 80, 40))
DF

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    eng1  eng2  eng3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    50   130    20
#> 2    40   100    10
#> 3    20   150    80
#> 4    30   200    40

DF %>% 
  select(starts_with("eng")) %>% 
  mutate(eng = pmap_dbl(., sum))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>    eng1  eng2  eng3   eng
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    50   130    20   200
#> 2    40   100    10   150
#> 3    20   150    80   250
#> 4    30   200    40   270

# or define a function
sumAll <- function(...) {
  x = c(...)
  sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

DF %>% 
  select(starts_with("eng")) %>% 
  mutate(eng = pmap_dbl(., sumAll))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>    eng1  eng2  eng3   eng
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    50   130    20   200
#> 2    40   100    10   150
#> 3    20   150    80   250
#> 4    30   200    40   270
```

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for the pmap_dbl heads up.